# Регулярное выражение исключающее арифметические операции в начале и в конце строки Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            strings.add(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(strings);
```

Есть регулярное выражение `("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)")`, которое разбивает строку на числа/дробные числа и на символы +/-/*/"/", как можно ее дополнить, чтобы отсекались арифметические операторы которые будут в начале строки или в конце( например
"+1+2-3*-*+" `-->` `[1, +, 2, -, 3]` ?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Предварительно удалите эти операторы с помощью `.replaceAll("^[-+/*]+|[-+/*]+$", "")`?

Comment: Или можно воспользоваться `"\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|(?<!^[-+*/]{0,100})[-+*/](?![-+*/]*$)"`

Comment: Что-нибудь сработало?

Comment: @Wiktor , извините, забыл отписать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отсечь арифметические операторы в начале или в конце строки, можно воспользоваться

```
.replaceAll("^[-+/*]+|[-+/*]+$", "")
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/tH8Mdy/1). Метод заменяет все вхождения регулярного выражения в строке.

**Подробности выражения**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[-+/*]+` - один и более символов, указанных в символьном классе: `-`, `+`, `/` и `*` (обратите внимание на то, что дефис (минус) находится в начале класса, если нужно добавить символы в класс, он должен остаться на этом месте)
- `|` - или
- `[-+/*]+` - один и более символов, указанных в символьном классе: `-`, `+`, `/` и `*`
- `$` - конец строки.

[Java-демо](https://ideone.com/FgKk0W):

```
String s = "+1+2-3-*+";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^[-+/*]+|[-+/*]+$", ""));
// => 1+2-3
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли